# Wrong output to a file, C++

Tags: c++, output

I am trying to output some numbers to a file. Here's how:

```
std::ofstream out;
out.open("%path%/perm.out");
if (Pos == N)
{
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        out << a[i] << " ";
    out << "\n";
    return;
}
```

I expect the result to look like this, since I'm trying to calculate permutations:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

However, what I get is this:

```
3 2 1
```

But if I try to output this to console using std::cout, I get the result which I expected. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible to show more code? The problem does not seem obvious from this section alone.

Comment: @benson-lin I surely would, but I don't know what to post! There is no other output in the code. Just the rest of the algorithm which calculates permutations and main.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code you posted prints only a line of data. That's fine for stdout, but a file would be rewritten every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file in Append mode.

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt", ios::app);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not clear I expect that the code you displayed is inside a function.
The problem might be that you are overriding the same file again and again so at the end you are just having only the last line.

```
3 2 1
```

Please put more code so that any one can understand what the problem is.